# Otimização Linked Server SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, otimização, linked-server

Atualmente tem um ambiente que possui 4 servidores com base de dados. Preciso reunir algumas informações de 3 servidores em 1.

**Exemplo**:

Os servidores são: **A** **B** **C** e **D**

Preciso pegar algumas informações que estão nos servidores **A** **B** **C** e colocar na base de dados do **D**.

A minha maior preocupação agora é com a otimização desse processo, pois são muitos dados, a tabela de uma base de dados já tem mais de 1 milhão de registros.

Com base nesse senário, usando o linked server o que seria melhor. 
Os servidores **A** **B** **C** enviar as informações para o **D**. Ou o servidor **D** buscar esses dados nos outros servidores?

Todas as base de dados estão no SQL Server 2014.

**DETALHES DA INFRA**

- A versão do Sql Server é 13.0.1601.5;
- Os servidores são todos Windows Server 2012;
- Estão na mesma rede;
- A configuração dos servidores é: Processador: Xeon E5 2GHz | 8 Gb memoria ram | disco scsi;
- E tem vários outros processos rodando nas base de dados;

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

- A versão dos SQL Server são Entreprise;
- Tenho acesso a usuário sysadmin;

Comment: Pode dar mais detalhes sobre a infra Diego? Como os servidores A B C se comunicam com D ? Qual versão do SQL Server 2014 em cada uma dessas instancias? Dependendo da sua resposta existem soluções melhores

Comment: Isso vai ser feito uma vez só?

Comment: Isso será executado diariamente a noite. Obtendo os dados novos das tabelas. Só no começo que será massivo, pois tenho que obter os dados de 3 anos atras.

Comment: Nesse cenário, linked server pode atender bem. A 1a vez vai demorar, mas será uma única vez. Depois vai entrar na rotina e poucos dados serão importados diariamente. Enfim, eu faria o D buscar de A,B,C, um ponto único de manunteção.

Comment: @cantoni realmente ainda não tinha pensando nessa questão da manutenção.

Comment: Configurar replication nesse caso pode valer mais a pena. Versão quero dizer qual o tipo da licença (Standard, etc) e se você ou o dba tem permissão para administrar a instancia.

Comment: @gmsantos. Os SQL Server são Enterprise. Meu usuário é sysadmin de todas as bases.

Comment: @DiegoMoreno, se o problema ainda estiver pendente, qual é o critério para pegar informações nos servidores A, B e C e transferi-las para o servidor D?  
Haveria como, em cada servidor de origem (A, B e C), decidir o que enviar para o servidor D sem que fosse necessário consultar volume elevado de dados do servidor D?